# Detect button press on Bluetooth device in c# window form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Bluetooth microphone which has volume buttons that can control the volume on the source device

How can I do this?

I can see the device via this code below, but what can I do with it?

```
public void FillSoundDevicesInCombobox()
            {
    
                var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
                foreach (var endpoint in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show($"{endpoint.FriendlyName} {endpoint.ID}");
                    CB1.Items.Add(endpoint.FriendlyName);
                }
```

On second thoughts, it will have to be a direct receive from the device. The reason is if it were sending conventional VOLUME_UP and DOWN messages, Windows would have responded already. For some reasons only certain media applications are responding to it's volume commands: